# Inclusion in $L_p$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I have been wondering how to prove the following statement, and would greatly appreciate your help:

If $f$ is a bounded function on $E$ that belongs to $L_{p_1}(E)$, then it belongs to $L_{p_2}(E)$ for any $p_2>p_1$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use Hölder's inequality

Comment: @Cortizol That's really an answer. Since there's not a lot to do here.

Comment: Sorry, but what is $E$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to get this result from Hölder's inequality, but I offer the following <strike>profound</strike> observation: if $|y|\le M$, then 
$$|y|^{p_2}\le M^{p_2-p_1}|y|^{p_1}$$
I hope this is sufficient for the OP.